# How to get the offset of the cursor position from the visible area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the cursor offset (not the cursor position) from the top of the view of a textarea.

`e.target.selectionStart` gives me the cursor position.
`$el.scrollTop` gives me the scroll offset of the textarea.

How do I calculate the offset into the visible area of the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

hope what you want is what i've understood, which is you want to get the offset of the mouse inside text area ignoring the scroll position, here is an example:

```
const area = document.getElementById("textarea");

area.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  var ofsetY = e.offsetY;
});
```